# c# Webbrowser - identify javascript function by div id

Tags: javascript

actually i´m having some trouble with a webiste.
I´m trying to get a div content that is created by a javascript.
Sadly I can´t figure out which Javascript actually is filling this div.

How could I find that script ?

```
<div id="messageContent" class="msg_content textBeefy textCenter">
    <script> 
        <form action="http://s124-de.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=messages&displayCategory=9&displayPage=1" name="delMsg" method="POST">
            <input id="new_msg_count" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <table id="mailz" class="list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="first">
                    <tr id="TR30739146" class="entry trigger " />
                    <tr id="TR30738105" class="entry trigger alt" />
                    <tr id="TR30734795" class="entry trigger " />
                    <tr id="TR30734031" class="entry trigger alt" />
                    <tr id="TR30731272" class="entry trigger " />
                    <tr class="last" />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
```

The tables including those TR30739... are created by that unkown script.

I´ve tried to checkout the scripts I found with firebug one by one but I´m not sure if I´m calling them correctly and may not notice if it´s the one I´m looking for.

Comment: I've added indents to your markup - where are closing tags for script and div? What does <script> tag is actually doing there?

Comment: It´s copied out of firebug.(firefox)
<script> contains a java code

Comment: @user3179347: *<script> contains a java code"* No, it doesn't. It might contain *JavaScript*, though, an entirely different language...

Comment: Chrome showed me this when I followed T.J`S instructions:
(function(e,t){var n,r,i=typeof t,o=e.document,a=e.location,s=e.jQuery,u=e.$,l={}

the code goes on for like 300 lines... ><
is this a function i ca execute or do i need to get more..."deep" ?

Comment: What is "C# Webbrowser"? Does it execute javascript?

Comment: it´s a Webbrowser component in c#

Btw it seems like the whole java script is on another server.
Is that possible ?
Chrome shows as title something like this
ajskdnkabsdkj13bkjb123hjb231jkad.js
and at the source window it´s within an other url.

Comment: i´ve loacted the script
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://gf3.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnef/56996a817665f19c0402f4f3c32c00.js'></script>

can i just execute it with
browser.Document.InvokeScript("http://gf3.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnef/56996a817665f19c0402f4f3c32c00.js");

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question boils down to: How do I know what code is modifying a given DOM element?

You can do that with Chrome's Dev Tools (probably others as well), if you can get a chance to set a "DOM breakpoint" before the code in question runs:

1. Open the page
2. Open Dev Tools
3. Right-click the table and click Inspect
4. Right-click the table element in the DOM window and choose **Break on... > Subtree modifications**

Then when the table is modified, Chrome will stop the script and show you where the modification is happening in the JavaScript code. Then if you look at the call stack you should be able to find the code in question.

The trick, of course, is getting the breakpoint set before the code modifying the table runs.

Another option, again with Chrome, is to use the old deprecated mutation events. The new (and in most ways better) `MutationObserver` callbacks are not made synchronously with the code modifying the DOM, but old mutation event callbacks are:

1. Open a blank tab
2. Open Dev Tools
3. In the console, type (but don't press Enter yet)

   ```
   function setBreak() { var elm = document.getElementById("mailz"); if (!elm) { setTimeout(setBreak); return; } elm.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function() { debugger; }); } setBreak();
   ```
4. In the address bar, paste the page's URL and then **as quickly as possible* switch back to the console and press Enter

Or of course, if you can modify the content of the page, just put that in a `script` element.

That code looks for the `mailz` element and, if it finds it, sets a `DOMSubtreeModified` listener on it that uses the `debugger;` statement. If the code doesn't see the element (yet), it schedules itself to run again at the next opportunity. When the event fires, the `debugger;` statement tells Chrome to stop the code and bring up the source pane. Then, again, inspect the call stack.